# How to implement search over shared documents

Tags: elasticsearch, authorization

In our application we allow users to like and share documents. We would like to be able to perform an Elasticsearch query over all documents relevant to a specific user (liked and shared documents) but without storing any authorization fields in Elasticsearch (since updating these would be pretty slow).
Are there any standard ways of architecting a solution for this?

Comment: Have you thought of indexing the data based on user, and simply searching on those data?

Comment: You mean making duplicates of a document per user or adding a field in a document that includes all users that have access to it?